# how to iterate over xlsx data in octave with mixed types

Tags: octave

I am trying to read a simple xlsx file with xlsread in octave. Its csv version is shown below:

```
2,4,abc,6
8,10,pqr,12
14,16,xyz,18
```

I am trying to read and write the contents with this code:

```
[~, ~, RAW] = xlsread('file.xlsx');
allData = cell2mat(RAW);  # error with cell2mat()
printf('data nrows=%d, ncolms=%d\n', rows(allData), columns(allData));
for i=1:rows(allData)
   for j=1:columns(allData)
      printf('data(%d,%d) = %d\n', i,j, allData(i,j));
   endfor
endfor
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
error: cell2mat: wrong type elements or mixed cells, structs, and matrices
```

I have experimented with several variations of this problem:

(A)  If I delete the column with the text data, ie the xlsx file contains only numbers, then this code works fine.

(B) On the other hand, if I delete the cell2mat() call even for the purely number xlsx, I get an error during the cell access:

```
error: printf: wrong type argument 'cell'
```

(C) If I use cell2mat() during printf, like this:

```
printf('data(%d,%d) = %d\n', i,j, cell2mat(allData(i,j)));
```

I get correct data for the integers, and garbage for the text items.

So, how can I access and print each cell of the xlsx data, when the xlsx contains mixed-type data?

In other words, given a column index, and given that I know what type of data I am expecting there (integer or string), so how can I re-format the cell type before using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A numeric array cannot have multi-class data hence `cell2mat` fails. Cell-arrays are used to hold such type of data and you already have it in a cell array, so there is **no need of conversion** and so just skip that line (`allData = cell2mat(RAW);`).

Within the loop, you have this line:

```
printf('data(%d,%d) = %d\n', i, j, allData(i,j) );
%                      ↑                  ↑   ↑ 
%                      1                 2a   2b
```

<sup>The problems are represented by up-arrows.</sup>

1. You've mixed data in your cell array but you're using `%d` as the data specifier. You can fix this by converting all of your data to string and then use `%`s as the specifier.
2. If you use square brackets `( )` for indexing a cell array, you will get a cell. What you need here is the content of that cell and braces `{ }` are used for that.

So it will be:

```
printf('data(%d,%d) = %s\n', i,j, num2str(RAW{i,j}));
```

---

Note that instead of all that, you can simply just enter `RAW` to get this:

```
octave:1> RAW
RAW = 
{
  [1,1] =  2
  [2,1] =  8
  [3,1] =  14
  [1,2] =  4
  [2,2] =  10
  [3,2] =  16
  [1,3] = abc
  [2,3] = pqr
  [3,3] = xyz
  [1,4] =  6
  [2,4] =  12
  [3,4] =  18
}
```